# How can I encrypt multiple passwords to access multiple instances?

Tags: spring-boot, encryption, yaml, jasypt

In the `application.yml` file for my Spring Boot application, I'd like to define multiple instances of a service and in order to query each service, I'd have to use different tokens. These tokens are encrypted with Jasypt for protection.

The `application.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
service:
  urls: 
      https://url1,
      https://url2
  authorizations:
      ENC(encrypted_token1),
      ENC(encrypted_token2)
```

And I use:

```java
@Value("${service.urls}")
String[] urls;

@Value("${service.authorizations}")
String[] authorizations;
```

However this causes an exception when my application starts

```
Injection of autowired dependencies failed: nested exception is com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptsprintboot.exception.DescryptionException: Decryption of Properties failed, make sure encryption/decryption passwords match
```

I'm pretty sure the encryption and decryption was properly done because if I change the multiple URL values and tokens to just one URL and one token, everything works.